# No module named Pandas in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I know there is a huge number of questions on this topics, but not even one worked for me, not here, not on github.

I have installed anaconda2 for macOS a few days before. I know pandas come with Anaconda by default, and in the last year I haven't any trouble with any python package on Ubuntu, but now I have a weird problem. 
When I run jupyter notebook and `import pandas as pd`, I got an error: `no module named pandas`. It's not just about pandas, none of libraries work.

When I try to install pandas with conda, return me `Requirement already satisfied`. The same with pip.
Also, I have tried to run jupyter notebook with a full path to jupyter package, and doesn't help either. 
Probably there is a problem with PATH, but I'm not really good with that and not sure what to do.

But everything works fine when I run iPython in terminal, python in terminal, just doesn't work in jupyter notebook.

```
> python --version
: Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.

> which python :/anaconda2/bin/python

> which jupyter-notebook:
/anaconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook

> conda env list:
 conda environments:
base                  *  /anaconda2
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If you run `!which python` in your notebook, do you get the expected interpreter? If not, check if "Kernel -> Change kernel" allows you to pick between different ones.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in jupyter cell:

```
!pip install pandas
```